# Using Texture in ImageView

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android native. I use game frameworks for making games.

Recently I was building a app that has an imageView. I can attach an drawable to it very easily. But now what I need is a dynamic image. 
For example consider a square image.
Divide it into 4
1st half is filled with red,2nd is filled with green,3rd with yellow and 4th with blue.
In gameframeworks we can create a texture on the fly and use it. Is there any such option in android native?

Comment: You can create a tablelayout with views for each row/column and set their backgrounds appropriately if what you want to accomplish is simply what's described

Comment: That will be very heavy. I have a very small imageview

Comment: I don't think you can assign quadrants to views, I think that they would each have to be independent if you planned on them being independently dynamic

Comment: can I do something like create a custom ImageView and override its draw function?

Comment: Yea sorry didn't know how comfortable you were with the code. You can make your own custom views and override their drawing functionality yes